Application-defined or object-defined error for copy + paste macro
Here's my code, but it keeps giving me the app defined error, any help here, it's for a copy + paste macro.
Option Explicit

Sub CopyECR() 

Dim ECRCol As Range
Dim ECR As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set ECRCol = Sheet1.Range("H2:H1000")

For Each ECR In ECRCol
    If Sheet2.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    If ECR = "Yes" Then Range(ECR.End(xlToLeft), ECR.End(xlToRight)).Copy PasteCell

Next ECR

Tried to write a macro that would copy + paste a certain list of cells, but it won't work.

Which line throws the error?

You need Sheet1.Range(ECR.End(xlToLeft), ECR.End(xlToRight)).Copy or it may try to use the ActiveSheet and not Sheet1

Also see how to find the last used cell.
